# How can I call a function on shell.parse() without first assigning to a variable? for example shell.parse().someFunction()

Tags: groovy

Right now I'm doing this:

```
//main.groovy
def func = shell.parse( new File('func.groovy') )
func.someMethod('sdfsdfsdfsdf')

//func.groovy
def someMethod(deploymentFolder) {
    return deploymentFolder
}
```

I want to make the snippet in main.groovy a one-liner but this does not work:

```
def func = shell.parse( new File('func.groovy') ).someMethod('sdfsdfsdf')
```

and this doesn't work either:

```
def func = shell.parse( new File('func.groovy') ) someMethod('sdfsdfsdf')
```

Is there a way to call a function directly on what shell.parse returns like this?

### Edit

I am calling this in a collect call which seems to change things

So this is not working:

```
list = arrList.collect { file ->
    return shell.parse( new File(file) ).someMethod('sdfsdfsdf')
}
```

someMethod() returns an arrayList. after collect though list seems to contain the right number of nested lists but they are all null.

Yet doing this actually works:

```
myarr = []
list = arrList.collect { file ->
    tempVar = shell.parse( new File(file) )
    myarr += tempVar.someMethod('sdfsdfsdf')
}
```

I'm not sure what the difference is. I thought collect would do the same thing. It seems to *almost* do the same thing but the lists it concatenates are all null.

Comment: `def func` will be result of someMethod - your first version seems allright.  please add what "does not work" mean to your question.

Comment: This still works just fine.  Are you able to share your exact thing, that is not working as expected?  E.g. also what groovy version you are using etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt there is right and works as suspected:

```
def shell = new GroovyShell()
println(["func.groovy"].collect{ it as File }.collect{ shell.parse(it).someMethod('sdfsdfsdfsdf') })
// ⇒ [sdfsdfsdfsdf]
```